# #import in objective C: Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, import

Sorry, couldn't find a more appropriate title.

In My code I have two classes which should know of each others existence. So I use an instance variable which points to the other class. For that to work (I guess?) the other classes headers file should be imported so it knows which methods it has and such.

Here is my code (stripped down)

MainMenuController.h:

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import "IRCConnection.h"

    @interface MainMenuController : NSViewController {    
        IRCConnection *ircConnection;
    }

    @property (strong) IRCConnection *ircConnection;

    @end
```

IRCConnection.h:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "MainMenuController.h"

    @interface IRCConnection : NSObject {

        MainMenuController *mainMenuController;
    }

    @property (strong) MainMenuController *mainMenuController;

    @end
```

As you can see they both import each other, but this creates an error (Unknown type name 'IRCConnection') in one, and in the other Unknown type name 'MainMenuController'.

However when the connection is just one way (e.g. only MainMenuController knows about IRCConnection) and thus there is only an import statement in one of the two, it works fine.

How can I have them to know about each other? In both ways.

Hope this question makes any sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could remove the import from `IRCConnection.h` and use a `@class` statement instead.

like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class MainMenuController;

@interface IRCConnection : NSObject {
```

then add a `#import "MainMenuController.h"` to `IRCConnection.m`

Comment: There is no "correct way", but common practice is to `#import` frameworks and use `@class` for other classes in header files. In implementation (`.m`) files then you can `#import` everything you've `@class`ed in your `.h` file. This practice helps avoid `#import` loops and double `#imports`.

Comment: I'd say `@class` in `.h` and `#import` in `.m` is the closest thing to a "correct way" there is. It's definitely accepted practice at least.

Comment: If you don't really need the IRCConnection to have the view controller be a MainMenuController, you could also declare it as NSViewController instead. Of course, then you can only call methods from that parent class.

Answer (score 3):

In the header, use forward declaration:

```
@class IRCConnection;

@interface MainMenuController : NSViewController {    
    IRCConnection *ircConnection; // ok
}
```

In the source file (`.m`), do `#import`.

Comment: Using it this way the class does not know of any methods declared in IRCConnection, so I cannot call those. The error I get is:

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have circular imports. You need to break them up, or introduce some forward declarations.

Comment: And how could I accomplish such thing?

Comment: Like the other answers say, with @class.  Or don't have the IRCConnection depend on the view controller.